# How to set the arrival rate of pedsource and conctrol the total flow rate?

Tags: anylogic

Now I set the pedSource and pedGoto to simulate a sidewalk environment. And there are three types of agents. I try to use the arrival rate in pedSource to control the flow rate of the sidewalk environment. However, I don't understand how it works in Anylogic (I think the arrival rate may be the number of people arriving at the target line per unit time).

For example, I want to set the pedestrian flow rate: 16 ped/min, and the average speed : >1.3m/s.
so I set the arrival rate: 10 agent/min.
I observed the change of average speed and found that it can not always be greater than 1.3m/s  until all agents pass (sometimes will lower than 0.7m/s).

How can I control the flow rate and average speed?

Thanks!

Comment: Your ask is unclear. Please try to add screenshots of your model.

Comment: Your average speed also depends on the accelerations/curves etc the agent takes, so it could be that this is the issue